# Android: Why cant i save more objects in my arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

why is that when i make a touched pinpoint, it only takes the last pinpoints in the arraylist. When i measure the arraylist size, it says that the size is 1 even though I am saving 2 or more pinpoints.

GoogleMaps Class.

```
public class GoogleMaps extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {



public void addLocation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setTitle("What do you want to call the location?");
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            checklocationTitle();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert.show();
}


public void checklocationTitle() {
    if (value.length() > 3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name of the locations is know " + value,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            markedpinpoint = true;
            midllat = touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            midlongi = touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> adress = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                    touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
            if (adress.size() > 0) {
                String display = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < adress.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    display += adress.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint,
                            value, display);
                    custom = new Location_Service(d, GoogleMaps.this);
                    custom.insertLocation(overlayitem);
                    overlayList.add(custom);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "There where a problem to locate the selected adresse",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Please provide a least 3 cifre Title for your location.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        addLocation();
    }
}


public void buttonLocations(View view) {
    // stopLocationListner();
    // stopBackgroundService();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PinPoints.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Gemte steder: " + custom.size(),
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Location_Service Class

```
public class Location_Service extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    public ArrayList<OverlayItem> pinpoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public Location_Service(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ArrayList<Locations> getData() {
        Locations hej = new Locations();
        ArrayList<Locations> tt = new ArrayList<Locations>();
        for (OverlayItem test : pinpoints) {
            hej.setAdress(test.getSnippet());
            hej.setMidlat(test.getPoint().getLatitudeE6());
            hej.setMidlong(test.getPoint().getLongitudeE6());
            hej.setTitle(test.getTitle());
            tt.add(hej);
        }
        return tt;
    }

    public Location_Service(Drawable m, Context context) {
        this(m);
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return pinpoints.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return pinpoints.size();
    }

    public void insertLocation(OverlayItem item) {
        pinpoints.add(item);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code that uses this overlay?

Comment: Please never ever use an empty catch block! At least log something so you can see that there was an exception thrown and catched. An empty catch block is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the same Locations object to the list repeatedly in `getData()`... you're not instantiating a new object.

You probably really meant

```
ArrayList<Locations> tt = new ArrayList<Locations>();
for (OverlayItem test : pinpoints) {
    Locations hej = new Locations(); //instantiate each time!
    hej.setAdress(test.getSnippet());
    hej.setMidlat(test.getPoint().getLatitudeE6());
    hej.setMidlong(test.getPoint().getLongitudeE6());
    hej.setTitle(test.getTitle());
    tt.add(hej);
}
return tt;
```

Comment: Nice cach @RonU, but the same problem appears, arraylist size is still only showing 1 even though i'm marking 4 pin points.